# How do you run a Javascript function in an interval that starts at the end of callback execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval

I run a function in Javascript asynchronously by using the setinterval function.

```
myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
```

The execution of the myTimer function can be quite long, sometimes longer than the specified delay, in that case the intervals just get executed back to back. I would like the next execution of the callback function to be scheduled in relationship with the end of the execution of the previous. To restate I want the myTimer function to run after 5000 ms of when previous finishes and wanted this to repeat.

Comment: Probably a wrapper over `setTimneout`, which calls itself when callback is done?

Comment: Can you tell me more about `myTimer`?

Can we catch event `done` of that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done using `setTimeout` instead.

```js
function myTimer(){
   console.log("Exec func");
   // Rest of the functionality here
   setTimeout(myTimer, 5000);
}

myTimer();
```

Comment: He wants "run after 5000 ms of when previous finishes", your code same `setInterval`

Comment: It is not the same code, because the rest of the functionality gets executed before the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
function longFunction() {
  // Do your stuff here
}

var taskId;

function task() {
  longFunction();
  taskId = setTimeout(task, 5000);
}
```