# Can something interrupt the timing of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

[How do you run a Javascript function in an interval that starts at the end of callback execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59822925/847773)

My post is a continuation of the previous question posted above. I was confused about setInterval. I wanted the interval to start after the time the previous execution of the function ends. I got a answer.
I started using setTimeout. Calling the function itself inside. It worked for a while.

Now occasionally there is some strange behaviour. I am struggling to diagnose it.

I am pasting my function at the bottom. You do not have to read all of it. The functions is running auditory recordings of digits and after issues a prompt, which stops execution and after the user answers there is a five second timeout after which the function is run again. More often than not it works fine, however some times after more execution it starts running closer and closer together, the timeout reduces from 5 seconds to almost nothing eventually. This does not happen in all contexts, so I do not think there is anything wrong in the function, which I posted. My question is what could change this schedule in the call stack? Some of the other code that is running might delay the start of the function(I could live with that), however the next call should still start 5000 ms after since it is executed after the audio ends.

I did not include all the other code that is running simultaneously, because there is simply too much of it.

```
function myTimer() {
    var auditoryRoundNumber = gorilla.retrieve("auditoryRoundNumber", 0);
    console.log("arn "+auditoryRoundNumber);
    const queue = [];
    var two_back=gorilla.retrieve("two_back", queue);

    if(auditoryRoundNumber<2){
        //console.log(auditoryRoundNumber);
        randint= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }else{
        //after the first two trials we assign a higher probability to the digit that happen two trials ago.

        //We make a draw in 50% of the cases it is a random digit in the other 50% it is the two back
        var draw=Math.random();
        if(draw>0.5){
            randint= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        }else{
            randint= two_back[0];
            //console.log(randint);
        }
    }
    two_back.push(randint);
    randstimuli=gorilla.stimuliURL(mdict[randint]);
    //console.log(randstimuli);
    var audio = new Audio(randstimuli);
    audio.play();
    //var interval=5000;//(audioInterval=="Fixed") ? 5000 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)+1000;

    audio.onended=function(){
        auditoryRoundNumber=auditoryRoundNumber+1;
        gorilla.store("auditoryRoundNumber",auditoryRoundNumber);
        //In the first two trial we do not ask what is the number two steps ago.
        if(auditoryRoundNumber>2){
            var start=Date.now();
            var ans=prompt("Was the last number the same as the one two steps ago? Y-Yes/N-No");
            ans=input_validation(ans);
            //console.log(two_back.length); 
            ans=(ans=="y"||ans=="Y")? 1: 0;
            //We remove the first item from the queue other items get reindexed
            two_back_ans= two_back.shift();
            //console.log(two_back_ans+" "+ (ans==two_back_ans)? 1:0);
            gorilla.metric({
                current_int: randint,
                two_back_int: two_back_ans,
                response_audio: ans,
                audio_correct: (ans==(randint==two_back_ans))? 1:0,//expressions to evaluate similarity between ans and 2-back
                audio_RT: Date.now()-start
            });
            //console.log(auditoryRoundNumber);

            if(auditoryRoundNumber>= NoOfAudioTrials+2){
                return;
            }
        }else{
            gorilla.metric({
                current_int: randint,
            });
        }
        gorilla.store("two_back", two_back);
        task_id=setTimeout(myTimer,5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add a function to be called after 5000 milliseconds, that's going to be *at least* 5000 milliseconds, not *exactly* that amount. The code runs in a single thread, so if after the delay the thread is currently executing something, then it will not be able to run your delayed code *right now*

Comment: I understand that and I am fine with that, however it seems that after my interval is extended in further executions the interval gets smaller.

Comment: i see you never cleartimeout with id `task_id`, I will recommend clearTimeout before running new

Comment: Why? Clear timeout prevents the function the execute.